Obtaining palindrome by permute-and-add
Recently, I've learnt about the Lychrel process where a number is reversed, the result is added to the number, and the process is repeated until a number becomes palindrome.
I modified the process by allowing any permutations other than simply reversing. So as an example, here's a path to palindrome for $196$ (which, in the normal Lychrel process, is conjectured to never reach a palindrome).
$$196 \rightarrow 196+961 = 1157 \rightarrow 1157+1175 = 2332$$
I found plenty of numbers requiring $3$ steps before a palindrome is reached. The smallest one is $86$. Here's one of the path
$$86 \rightarrow 86+86=172 \rightarrow 172 + 217 = 389 \rightarrow 389 + 398 = 787$$
But I couldn't find a number that requires $4$ steps. Can anyone prove/disprove that no such number such exists (i.e. all numbers requires at most $3$ steps of permute-and-add to reach a palindrome)?
